# How to Create Times Based on an Interval and Start Time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am performing some scheduling optimization in my database.

For the job schedule, many records appear like this

```
Time    NextRunTime
Every 3 hours   2019-06-03 10:00:00
Every 3 hours   2019-05-28 20:00:00
Every 4 hours   2017-07-31 18:00:00
Every 1 hours   2019-06-03 14:00:00
Every 4 hours   2017-06-08 16:00:00
```

What is an efficient means to split the "every" records into separate records within the 24 hour day?

For example, for the first record (every 3 hours from 10:00), I need it to insert the following into a table.

```
Time
13:00:00
16:00:00
19:00:00
22:00:00
01:00:00
04:00:00
07:00:00
10:00:00
```

I need to repeat this for every record in the first table with "every".

Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you have other "Times" in there other than "Every *x* hours"? What about "Every 10 minutes" or "Every Other Day", or perhaps "Once a month, on the 1st"?

Comment: @Larnu Yes, but, I excluded them from the question. It is the same idea and I didn't want to complicate the problem.

Comment: But the problem then is is that the answer that Alan has now taken the time to make for you won't work unless you have only values for hours. At the end of the day, however, SQL Server does not "speak" English; it can't read it, understand it, and then do *something* based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this correctly you will need a [tally table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1). First let's look at the logic required to solve this.

```
DECLARE @starttime DATETIME = '2019-06-03 10:00:00', @hours INT = 3;

SELECT t.N, Tm = CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,t.N*3,@startTime) AS TIME)
FROM
(
  SELECT TOP (24/@hours) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
  FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS a(x),
       (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS b(x)
) AS t(N);
```

**Returns:**

```
N       Tm
------- ----------------
1       13:00:00.0000000
2       16:00:00.0000000
3       19:00:00.0000000
4       22:00:00.0000000
5       01:00:00.0000000
6       04:00:00.0000000
7       07:00:00.0000000
8       10:00:00.0000000
```

Now for some sample data and a record identifier (named "someId") so we can calculate this for all rows in your table.

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (someId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, freq INT, NextRunTime DATETIME);
INSERT @yourTable(freq, NextRunTime) VALUES (3, '2019-06-03 10:00:00'),
                 (3, '2019-05-28 20:00:00'),(4, '2017-07-31 18:00:00'),
                 (1, '2019-06-03 14:00:00'),(4, '2017-06-08 16:00:00');

-- Solution                 
SELECT yt.someId, f.Tm 
FROM   @yourTable AS yt
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT t.N, CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,t.N*yt.freq,yt.NextRunTime) AS TIME)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP (24/yt.freq) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
    FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS a(x),
         (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS b(x)
  ) AS t(N)
) AS f(N,Tm);
```

**Returns:**

```
someId      Tm
----------- ----------------
1           13:00:00.0000000
1           16:00:00.0000000
1           19:00:00.0000000
1           22:00:00.0000000
1           01:00:00.0000000
1           04:00:00.0000000
1           07:00:00.0000000
1           10:00:00.0000000
2           23:00:00.0000000
2           02:00:00.0000000
2           05:00:00.0000000
2           08:00:00.0000000
2           11:00:00.0000000
2           14:00:00.0000000
2           17:00:00.0000000
2           20:00:00.0000000
3           22:00:00.0000000
3           02:00:00.0000000
3           06:00:00.0000000
3           10:00:00.0000000
3           14:00:00.0000000
3           18:00:00.0000000
4           15:00:00.0000000
4           16:00:00.0000000
4           17:00:00.0000000
4           18:00:00.0000000
4           19:00:00.0000000
4           20:00:00.0000000
4           21:00:00.0000000
4           22:00:00.0000000
4           23:00:00.0000000
4           00:00:00.0000000
4           01:00:00.0000000
4           02:00:00.0000000
4           03:00:00.0000000
4           04:00:00.0000000
4           05:00:00.0000000
4           06:00:00.0000000
4           07:00:00.0000000
4           08:00:00.0000000
4           09:00:00.0000000
4           10:00:00.0000000
4           11:00:00.0000000
4           12:00:00.0000000
4           13:00:00.0000000
4           14:00:00.0000000
5           20:00:00.0000000
5           00:00:00.0000000
5           04:00:00.0000000
5           08:00:00.0000000
5           12:00:00.0000000
5           16:00:00.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

I have always thought that a recursive cte is a nice way to solve your query:

```
-- the sample data
declare @data as table (freq varchar(100), tmst datetime, each_ int)
insert into @data
select s.freq,s.tmst,
  convert(int,replace(replace(freq,'Every ',''),' hours','')) as each_
from (
  select 'Every 4 hours' as freq, convert(datetime,'2019-06-02 10:00:00') as tmst union all
  select 'Every 3 hours' as freq, convert(datetime,'2019-06-02 11:00:00') as tmst union all
  select 'Every 2 hours' as freq, convert(datetime,'2019-06-02 10:00:00') as tmst
) s

-- the query
;with cte as ( 
  select freq, tmst, each_, null t1 from @data
  union all
  select freq, tmst, each_, isnull(t1,datepart(hour,tmst)) + each_
  from cte
  where isnull(t1,datepart(hour,tmst)) + each_ <= 23
)
select freq,
  isnull(convert(datetime, convert(varchar(8),tmst,112) + ' ' + (convert(varchar(100),t1) + ':00:00' ), 120),tmst)
from cte
order by 1, 2
```

With this second version, you can get all the ranges from 0 to 23 (in the previous example you got just from the starting point to the 23)

```
-- the query
;with findfirst as ( 
  select freq, tmst, datepart(hour,tmst) as fhour, datepart(hour,tmst) as init, each_ from @data
  union all
  select freq, tmst, fhour, init - each_, each_ from findfirst where init - each_ >= 0
),
cte as ( 
  select min(init) as init, freq, tmst, each_, fhour from findfirst group by freq, tmst, each_, fhour
  union all
  select init + each_, freq, tmst, each_, fhour from cte where init + each_ <= 23
)
select freq,tmst,convert(time, right('0' + convert(varchar(2),init), 2) + ':00:00')
from cte order by freq,init,each_
```

Remember to continue using the `@data` table.

Output:

[image: output query 2]

Comment: Recursive CTEs for this type of thing will perform terribly and generate a huge amount of IO. If you run what you posted with SET STATISTICS IO ON you'll see that it generates 93 reads to return 18 rows. Here's a good read on the topic: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hidden-rbar-counting-with-recursive-ctes

Comment: This always depends on the amount of data we talk about

Comment: In addition, I said it's a nice way... in terms of logical way, I still think is nice

Answer (score 0):

First drop any temp tables that have the names of the temp tables you will create:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Interval', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Interval
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Interval2', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Interval2
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Runstart', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Runstart
GO
```

Then create, and insert data into, your temp tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #Interval
(
_Time NVARCHAR(13),
NextRunTime DATETIME
)
GO
INSERT INTO #Interval VALUES ('Every 3 hours','2019-06-03 10:00:00')
INSERT INTO #Interval VALUES ('Every 3 hours','2019-05-28 20:00:00')
INSERT INTO #Interval VALUES ('Every 4 hours','2017-07-31 18:00:00')
INSERT INTO #Interval VALUES ('Every 1 hours','2019-06-03 14:00:00')
INSERT INTO #Interval VALUES ('Every 4 hours','2017-06-08 16:00:00')
GO

CREATE TABLE #Interval2
(
RunID INT IDENTITY(10001,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
_Time INT NOT NULL,
NextRunTime DATETIME NOT NULL
)
GO
```

The code below ensures that you get the right interval for each run start, note: If the number of hours are ever 10 or more, it would be necessary to add some more code here to make the number of digits selected conditional upon the length of the string which contains them, let me know if you need this code too.

```
INSERT INTO #Interval2 (_TIME,NextRunTime) SELECT SUBSTRING(_Time,7,1),NextRunTime FROM #Interval WHERE LEFT(_Time,5) = 'Every'
GO

CREATE TABLE #Runstart
(
StartID INT IDENTITY(10001,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
RunID INT NOT NULL,
[Start_DTTM] DATETIME
)
GO
```

Next populate the #RUNSTART table using this loop:

```
DECLARE @RunID INT = 10001
DECLARE @RunTime INT = (SELECT _TIME FROM #Interval2 WHERE RunID = @RunID)
DECLARE @NextRun DATETIME = (SELECT NextRunTime FROM #Interval2 WHERE RunID = @RunID)

WHILE @RunID <= (SELECT MAX(RunID) FROM #Interval2)

BEGIN

WHILE @NextRun < (SELECT DATEADD(DD,1,NextRunTime) FROM #Interval2 WHERE RunID = @RunID)

BEGIN

INSERT INTO #Runstart (RunID,[Start_DTTM]) SELECT @RunID,DATEADD(HH,@RunTime,@NextRun)

SET @NextRun = (SELECT DATEADD(HH,@RunTime,@NextRun))

END

SET @RunID = @RunID+1
SET @RunTime = (SELECT _TIME FROM #Interval2 WHERE RunID = @RunID)
SET @NextRun = (SELECT NextRunTime FROM #Interval2 WHERE RunID = @RunID)

END
GO

SELECT StartID, RunID,CONVERT(VARCHAR,START_DTTM,108) AS Start_time FROM #RUNSTART
```

Comment: This is RBAR to the MAX. You want to avoid loops (such as WHILE loops) for row-by-row processing in SQL Server. The code is overly verbose and the performance is worse than terrible.

Comment: Sour grapes considering I got ten points. I don't see what the performance issue is with an answer which takes under a second to run. I have no idea what RBAR could mean. What's so verbose about a single line of code surrounded by a few variable resets? I don't appreciate this kind of criticism, why don't you get on with your own answers and comment if you've got something constructive to say.